# How to connect 14 thread pipe to 18 thread pipe

Tags: pipe, dryer, gas, threading

I am trying to install a gas dryer. I noticed that the gas pipe from the dryer (yellow) wouldn't lock with the gas pipe coming from the ground. They are both the same size, and I can turn for one thread, but then it becomes impossible. My suspicion is they might have different size thread. I counted 6 threads in approx 11 mm on the pipe coming from the ground and 5 threads in about 8 mm in the flange on the pipe coming from the dryer. My measurements were crude but these come close to a 14 threads per inch on the pipe coming from the ground and 18 threads per inch in the pipe from the dryer.

What would be some of the ways to connect these two? I can't figure out any adapter from Home Depot or Lowe's website.

[image]

Comment: A) make sure you thoroughly clean the threads of the pipe coming out of the ground or you won't get a leak proof connection. B) Make sure you _thoroughly_ test all connections, C) Try a local plumbing supply store, not a big box. D) Seriously consider hiring an HVAC guy or plumber to do the hook up to ensure you don't blow up the neighborhood.

Comment: A [thread pitch gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pitch_gauge) is the appropriate tool. [Threaded pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_pipe) threads are tapered so that they become tighter as you tighten the connection. It may feel like mismatched threads even though it is tightening and sealing as designed. (Ref. [NPT Standard Sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_pipe_thread#Standard_sizes).)

Comment: Thanks for the good point @HABO although I am very puzzled to buy a $8-9 piece. for that purpose. It will most likely sit useless for the years to come.

Comment: If have have 3/8" x 14 and 3/8" x 18 bolts at hand you can use them to verify that the threads on each side of the connection match the same bolt.

Comment: Don't have those bolts. But thanks for your response @HABO

Comment: @FreeMan A) Goes without saying. B) Goes without saying. C) That would be my first preference but they are hard to find and travel to. D) I will seriously consider. Thanks for you advice. Now if you know of any adapter or mating piece that will do the trick, you are welcome to share.

Comment: Gas appliance connectors (the yellow flex pipe) just about always use flare fittings. Flare fittings require adapters to mate with pipe threads (NPT pipes & fittings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 1/2" flare to 1/2" inch FIP coupler did the job. The dryer is happier than ever.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Aside of that very rusty pipe might need replacement using two wrenches (one to hold the vale one to unscrew and replace the pipe)

You need an adapter that looks like this.

[image: adapter]

Source: [adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0948LND71)

Comment: Thanks very much.